# Parental rights and other legal implication of a marriage of convenience for a lesbian couple in MD

Tags: united-states, marriage, maryland

My friend is considering a marriage of convenience with another women, as both will gain a sizeable discount from their 'spouses' place of employment if married, in addition to sharing health insurance.  There is no romantic relationship, no intent to co-mingle assets or live together, and a plan to get divorced in 4-5 years once they no longer gain a benefit from the marriage. I'm looking to understand any and all legal implications and risks which could affect my friend.

My friend already has a daughter and would likely have another child, conceived using a sperm donor, while 'married'.  She is located, and would be married, in Maryland.

As I understand Maryland law the wife would be a presumed parent, with both visitation rights and obligation to pay child support, in this case?  Is there any means at all for my friend to prevent or avoid the likelihood of presumed parentage causing her a problem in a marriage of convenience?

In addition are there any other legal risks or complications my friend should be aware of before deciding rather to get married in such a manner?

Answer (score -2):

Hard to ignore the rather grotesque notion of planning ahead to have a child but avoid "presumed parentage" (my first question would be, why even have the kid?)... but "your friend" should really talk to an attorney and not even because of the piddly reasons you laid out in your question, but to further inquire as to how much liability for fraud she would expose herself to under such a scheme

Comment: You apparently misunderstood the “presumed parentage” thing (the biological mother wants to be a parent). Ignoring that, this doesn’t seem to answer the question.

Comment: I'd like to see how you reach that definitive conclusion.

Comment: What, exactly, would be fraudulent about this, though?  Do you have any citations?

Comment: Plenty of convictions for that kind of thing in the UK (although cases involving two same sex partners are probably a lot rarer).

Comment: @Stackstuck it is fraud with every claim made that is dependent upon the marriage. Tax benefits, healthcare, etc. It's not so much the marriage itself that gets one in trouble, but it's the things the "couple" gains from the arrangements. This is assuming this is not an immigration case, by the way.

Comment: @A.fm. Then explain what makes it fraudulent.  You haven't cited _anything._

Comment: Read. Tax benefits, healthcare, etc. Taxes are the money citizens pay the government. Healthcare claims are when you cough and sneeze and must see someone who went to a lot of school to help you get better. Is that broken down far enough for you @Stackstuck?

Comment: _What makes.  The marriage.  Fraudulent._  _You haven't.  Explained that._  _There are no.  Citations._  @A.fm.

Comment: You're simply trolling now, @Stackstuck. One more time.  The definition of fraud is wrongful deception intended to result in financial or personal gain. I stated clearly a few comments ago that it may not necessarily be that the **marriage** itself is fraudulent (although I reckon it would be), but rather all the other things you receive as a part of being married could be considered fraudulent. This means that in the instance a crime is alleged, it may not be "Marriage Fraud" but it very well could be "tax fraud" if they claim the spousal-related tax breaks, as one example.

Comment: No, you're _not answering the question._  How, if the marriage is in order, would receiving benefits from it be fraudulent?  If it's _not_ in order, what makes it so?  _Explain, dammit._

Comment: Read OPs post. What don't you understand? The part where there is no romantic relationship? Where the motive to go through with the plan is money?  Or health insurance? Where they don't comingle money? Where after a predetermined amount of time they divorce after there is no longer any benefit? So the marriage is not "in order." But since I'm not sure there is a cause of action for that outside of the immigration context, that is how, conceivably, the crime alleged would not be the marriage, but rather the lies on the documents submitted to the government to receive the intended benefits.

Comment: @A.fm. what Stackstuck is saying is that the marriage isn't fraudulent.  They don't love each other, but no where in US law, that I'm aware of, does it say marriage requires love.  Marriage is a legal contractual agreement, *USUALLY* associated with romantic relationship, but not; as far as I know, legally required to.